# mySQL - How to SUM if alternate data is in columns

Tags: mysql

At first it looked like a simple challenge however I can not get my code to provide desired results.

I have a table rota in MySQL 5.5:

```
create table rota (
        code int(10) primary key,
    PN varchar(10),
        Alt varchar(10),
    Link varchar(10),
    PN_Val int(10),
    Alt_Val int(10));

insert into rota values (1, 'A',    'B',    '1',    1,  4);
insert into rota values (2, 'B',    'A',    '1',    4,  1);
insert into rota values (3, 'C',    '', '0',    3,  0);
insert into rota values (4, 'D',    'E',    '1',    3,  1);
insert into rota values (5, 'E',    'D',    '1',    1,  3);
insert into rota values (6, 'F',    'G',    '1',    1,  2);
insert into rota values (7, 'G',    'F',    '1',    2,  1);
```

And I am trying to get the below results without duplicates. I am missing something obvious but I need your help please! You can see that the table removes duplicates and has only one line for A, D and F.

```
PN  Alt Val
A   B   5
C       3
D   E   4
F   G   3
```

Comment: explain in more details, your question is not clear

Comment: Why is result for C 2 and not 3?

Comment: @Nick - corrected.

Comment: Please *edit your question* and include your query. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, your question is not really clear. Based on the data you have provided and your expected results, this query will do what you want. However it is reliant on there only being one `Alt` value for any given `PN` value, and that the `PN_Val` and `Alt_Val` values simply swap when the values of `PN` and `Alt` swap. These conditions are true in your sample data. The trick in this query is the `GROUP BY`, which gives rows with the same pair of `PN` and `Alt` values the same grouping value.

```
SELECT MIN(PN) AS PN, MAX(Alt) AS Alt,
    SUM(PN_Val + Alt_Val) / COUNT(PN_Val) AS Val
FROM rota
GROUP BY CONCAT(LEAST(PN, Alt), GREATEST(PN, Alt))
```

Output:

```
PN   Alt   Val
A    B     5 
C          3 
D    E     4 
F    G     3
```